# How to show AJAX response message in alert?

Tags: ajax, json

I am sending username and password as request parameter to the server in AJAX and trying to show the response message. But not able to showing the response message.In fiddler it is showing the response message. But while on the browser screen it is not showing.PLEASE somebody help me out where i am wrong or need to change anything..
I have written like this-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnCity").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://test.xyz.com/login",
      crossDomain: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: { username: "abc", password: "1234" },
      dataType: "JSONP",
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
      async: false,
      success: function (resdata) {
        alert(resdata);
      },
      error: function (result, status, err) {
        alert(result.responseText);
        alert(status.responseText);
        alert(err.Message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `resdata`?

Comment: What happens if you output just the resdata/err itself in a console.log? What browser are you in? I suspect this is b/c it returns JSON and you need to call resdata.parse() to be able to read it and display it. What happens? Do you get anything in the alert, or it just never shows up? Try just alerting some static data like 'blah' and see if you are actually hitting that code at all without it depending on that data.

Comment: do you get any output from the error function (`err.Message`)?

Comment: @Alek-I am not getting anything from resdata.It is direct going to the error section.

Comment: @rncrtr and Chresse-I am using chrome.m getting alerts from error section only as everything undefined. and sometimes getting parsererror,jquery12786762_212615 was not called,networkerror...

Comment: Are you XHR'ing a local file, rather than something that is actually being served by a network service (even if on localhost)? Because browsers often refuse to do that out of security considerations.

Comment: @Julian-no not a local file.how to give authentication ?

Comment: Could you check your developer tools(`F12`), especially the network tab and post the requests? Also post the any console errors.

Comment: @ GuyT--getting error 'undefined' all the time.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: I guess the problem is on the server side of your code (that we don't know yet).**

At first: I don't know why it fails for you. I've taken your code and ran it against a public available JSONP API, that returns the current IP of your system and it worked.

Please try yourself using the URL: `http://ip.jsontest.com/`.

So most probably, the server doesn't return the right response to the JSONP request. Have a look at the network tab in developer tools. With your current code, the answer of the server should be something like:

```
jsonCallback({'someResponseKeys': 'someResponseValue'});
```

Note: The header should contain `Content-Type:application/javascript`!

---

BTW, even if this doesn't for now solve your problem - here are some tweaks, I'd like to advice to you:

- Don't set `async` to false, at the documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) says:

  > Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous 
  >   operation.
- You don't need to set a `jsonpCallback`, because jQuery will generate and handle (using the `success` function a random one for you. Quote from the docs:

  > This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling.

So here comes my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnCity").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
      crossDomain: true,
      data: { username: "abc", password: "1234" },
      dataType: "JSONP",
      success: function (resdata) {
        console.log("success", resdata);
      },
      error: function (result, status, err) {
        console.log("error", result.responseText);
        console.log("error", status.responseText);
        console.log("error", err.Message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

A working [example can be found here](http://jsbin.com/jibirucu/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Another solution, like Yonatan Ayalon suggested, can be done with a predefined function and then setting the `jsonpCallback` explicitly to the function that should be called.

Comment: @concurrentHashMap- i had tried with URL: http://ip.jsontest.com/. and from there i was getting response successfully. After getting response from that url tried with my live url bt here m not getting the response.

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap-Thanks for your explainations it cleared some doubts of mine.

Answer (score 1):

if you see the response in Fiddler, it seems that the issue is in the callback function.

you are doing a jsonP call - which means that you need a callback function to "read" the response data.

Do you have a local function that calls "jsonCallback"?

this is a simple jsonP request, which initiates the function "gotBack()" with the response data:

```
            function gotBack(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://test.xyz.com/login' + '?callback=?',
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "gotBack"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following methods and close every instance of chrome browser in task manager, then open browser in web security disable mode by the command "chrome.exe --disable-web-security"

```
 success: function (resdata) {
        alert(resdata);
        alert(JSON.stringify(resdata));
    },
```

And the better option to debug the code using "debugger;"

```
success: function (resdata) {
            debugger;
            alert(resdata);
            alert(JSON.stringify(resdata));
        },
```

Comment: @pradeepta- My debug pointer is not coming to success area so how i ll try ur code ? :(